# jquery get .offset value of a variable(element) then animate to it

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, offset, var

I have a simple navigation.

```
<nav>
    <a href="#section1">page 1</a>
    <a href="#section2">page 2</a>
    <a href="#section3">page 3</a>
</nav>
```

When the user clicks on one of the links, I want the page to animate to the corresponding section on the page.

I can't seem to get the .offset().top value from a variable though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$("nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // figure out which button was clicked
    var targetName = $(this).attr("href");
    // get the current position of the target element
    var targetOffset = targetName.offset().top;
    // send the page there
    $("html, body").animate({
        top: targetOffset
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `targetName` is not a jQuery object, in your console you should see an error like `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
$("nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // figure out which button was clicked
    var targetName = $(this).attr("href");
    // get the current position of the target element
    var targetOffset = $(targetName).offset().top; //targetName is not  jQuery object
    // send the page there
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: targetOffset //also use scrollTop to animate scrolling
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/thcxsy7u/)

Comment: Thanks Arun! Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper object to animate to like Arun says, I was wrong - not thinking clearly :)

```
   $("nav a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // figure out which button was clicked
        var targetName = $(this).attr("href");
        // get the current position of the target element
        var targetOffset = $(targetName).offset().top;
        // send the page there
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: targetOffset
        }, 1400);
    });
```

example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/8L1uo2qd/2/)